# OpenAL: Sound track distorted and cutting off

Tags: c++, openal

I'm working on an OpenAL project also using the `libsndfile` library. I have a problem with playing soundtracks with long sound buffering in OpenAL. The sound is distorted in the beginning and just suddenly cuts off. Here is the base class snippet that determines and set the format of the clip and calculates the audio frame size:

```cpp
musicBuffer::musicBuffer(const char* filename){
    alGenSources(1, &se_source);

    alGenBuffers(num_buffers, se_buffers);

    std::size_t frame_size;



    //using sndfile to read the soundtrack
    se_sndfile = sf_open(filename, SFM_READ, &se_sfinfo);
    if (!se_sndfile){
        throw("could not open provided music file -- check path");
    }

    if (se_sfinfo.channels == 1)
        se_format = AL_FORMAT_MONO16;

    else if (se_sfinfo.channels == 2)
        se_format = AL_FORMAT_STEREO16;

    else if (se_sfinfo.channels == 3){
        if (sf_command(se_sndfile, SFC_WAVEX_GET_AMBISONIC, NULL, 0) == SF_AMBISONIC_B_FORMAT)
            se_format = AL_FORMAT_BFORMAT2D_16;
    }

    else if (se_sfinfo.channels == 4){
        if (sf_command(se_sndfile, SFC_WAVEX_GET_AMBISONIC, NULL, 0) == SF_AMBISONIC_B_FORMAT)
            se_format = AL_FORMAT_BFORMAT3D_16;
    }


    if (!se_format){
        sf_close(se_sndfile);
        se_sndfile = NULL;
        throw("Unsupported channel count from file");
    }


    frame_size = ((size_t)b_samples * (size_t)se_sfinfo.channels) * sizeof(short);
    se_membuf = static_cast<short*>(malloc(frame_size));

}
```

Also, it does not seem like the audio format would be the issue as this issue is present in all audio formats I use anyway. Below is the `Play()` and `updateBufferStream()` functions which gives all the relevant data to the audio buffers to be played:

```cpp
void musicBuffer::Play(){
    ALsizei i;

    
    alGetError();

    //rewinds source position + clear buffer
    alSourceRewind(se_source);
    alSourcei(se_source, AL_BUFFER, 0);

    //fill the buffer queue with info from sound file
    for (i = 0; i < num_buffers; i++){
        sf_count_t slen = sf_readf_short(se_sndfile, se_membuf, b_samples);
        if (slen < 1) break;

        slen *= se_sfinfo.channels * (sf_count_t)sizeof(short);
        alBufferData(se_buffers[i], se_format, se_membuf, (ALsizei)slen, se_sfinfo.samplerate);
    }

    if (alGetError() != AL_NO_ERROR){
        throw("Error buffering for playback");
    }

    //queue and start playback
    alSourceQueueBuffers(se_source, i, se_buffers);
    alSourcePlay(se_source);
    if (alGetError() != AL_NO_ERROR){
        throw("Error starting playback");
    }

}
```

```cpp
void musicBuffer::updateBufferStream(){
    ALint processed, state;


    alGetError();

    //check status of speakers
    alGetSourcei(se_source, AL_SOURCE_STATE, &state);
    //check amnt of buffers processed
    alGetSourcei(se_source, AL_BUFFERS_PROCESSED, &processed);

    if (alGetError() != AL_NO_ERROR)
    {
        throw("error checking music source state");
    }


    while (processed > 0){
        ALuint bufid;
        sf_count_t slen;

        alSourceUnqueueBuffers(se_source, 1, &bufid);
        processed--;

        //read the rest of the data, refill the buffers and re-queue
        slen = sf_readf_short(se_sndfile, se_membuf, b_samples);
        if (slen > 0){
            slen *= se_sfinfo.channels * (sf_count_t)sizeof(short);
            alBufferData(bufid, se_format, se_membuf, (ALsizei)slen,
                se_sfinfo.samplerate);
            alSourceQueueBuffers(se_source, 1, &bufid);
        }

        if (alGetError() != AL_NO_ERROR){
            throw("error buffering music data");
        }
    }

    //checking if source is underrun
    if (state != AL_PLAYING && state != AL_PAUSED){
        ALint queued;

        //if there isnt any buffers queued it means playback is done
        alGetSourcei(se_source, AL_BUFFERS_QUEUED, &queued);
        if (queued == 0)
            return;

        alSourcePlay(se_source);
        if (alGetError() != AL_NO_ERROR)
        {
            throw("error restarting music playback");
        }
    }

}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on what looks wrong or identify the issue itself?